# Javascript websocket working on multiple clients

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I have a php websocket running on my machine and I connect to it through Javascript like:

```
var connection = new Websocket('ws://localhost:8080');
```

It connects and runs fine as long as its running on the same machine I'm running my php server. I tried changing the connection to say 'ws://--ip address--:8080' but that doesn't work. In PHP I have

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 8080);
socket_listen($socket)
```

What do I need to change in order to listen from other computers? I am new to websockets and would like to know

Comment: `socket_bind($socket, '0.0.0.0', 8080);`  Definitely a duplicate of many other "why does this only work on localhost" questions.

Comment: Did you try to bind to server ip address (public ip).??